# Shopware 5 Custom Streams

Tags: cron, shopware5

I have a problem.
I have a Shopware 5 store and I want to show some content only for registered customers.
I am using the Shopware Custom Streams to make it work, but when a new customer comes in, I have to click into the customer account and set the Custom Stream rule.
How can I automate this so that all new registered customers automatically have the custom stream attributes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do that out of the box. but you could write a plugin, that subscribes to an event, after a new customer registers in the shop. Within the callback function of this event, you set the wanted customer stream to this customer.